# How to put this equation in java code?

Tags: java, math, equation

[image]

This is what I did but no matter what I keep getting infinity:

```
 public double calcr(){
  double cot = 1 / Math.tan(0);
  return  .5 * sideLength * cot * (Math.PI / numSides);
}
```

Main:

```
RegularPolygon poly = new RegularPolygon(4, 10);   
System.out.println(poly.calcr());
```

Output:

```
Inifinity
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `return sidelength / (2.0 * Math.tan(Math.PI / numSides))`

Answer (score 8):

The problem is that you do

```
double cot = 1 / Math.tan(0);
```

which will make `cot` be `Infinity`.

You'd want:

```
double cot = 1 / Math.tan(Math.PI / numSides);
return .5 * sideLength * cot;
```

Or, in a single line:

```
return .5 * sideLength / Math.tan(Math.PI / numSides);
```

Answer (score 1):

`tan(0)` is 0, so this line

```
double cot = 1 / Math.tan(0);
```

sets `cot` to `Infinity`. The computation below it will then also evaluate to Infinity, as you saw.

Since it looks like you're trying to evaluate `cot(pi/n)`, you'd need `1 / Math.tan(Math.PI / n)` instead of using `cot * (Math.PI / numSides)` with an incorrect value for `cot`.

Comment: But what do I pass in as a parameter then? Because to find cot its the reciprocal of tan, yet I need to pass something in.

Comment: @someone Editing, gimme a sec.

Comment: use `1 / Math.tan(Math.PI / n)`?